# loop to find parent id

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

Is it possible in C# to carry out a loop to find the parent id for a particular page?

Here's the scenario: I'm developing a breadcrumb. For each page I need the parent Id, so I can use that to populate a list with a url and a page title.

```
1st page --- Parent page --- Grandparent page
```

I need to be able to do a loop to gather the parent id, then that will populate the list which goes through and finds the new parent page parent id (basically for the grandparent page) and then populates the list until there aren't any more.

At the moment the current page data is stored in var `pageInSiteMap`:

```
var overview = new List<PageDataModel>();
pageInSiteMap // A get command is used to place the data in here
if(pageInSiteMap != null && pageInSiteMap.ParentId.HasValue)
{
     var parent = allpages.Data.Items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == pageInSiteMap.ParentId
     var parentEntry = new PageDataModel{
         pageUrl = parent.Url, pageTitle = parent.Title
     };
     overview.Add(parentEntry);
}
```

Comment: I've re-read your question several times and am struggling to see what exactly you're looking for? What is preventing you from looping?

Comment: I believe this current code will only get the first parent Id but not the grandparent, I'm not really good a loops so is there a way to implement one in.

Comment: now I am reading it for 6th time...

Comment: Sorry about it not making sense but essentially in the database a parentId is placed for each page. So its just like getting a list of parents, upon parents to form a breadcrumb list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to take a stab at this and assume you need recursion, here is a quick example I wrote:

```
public class Page
    {
        public int PageId { get; set; }

        public string PageTitle { get; set; }

        public Page Parent { get; set; }
    }

    public class Class1
    {
        public List<Page> GetPages(Page currentPage)
        {
            var ret = new List<Page> {currentPage};
            if(currentPage.Parent != null)
                ret.AddRange(GetPages(currentPage.Parent));
            return ret;
        } 
    }
```